# Find query in mongodb using cases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of product in which I have document like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5acb1dad698eaa7a254c9017"),
"txtProductCode" : "1233A",
"txtModelCode" : "00M",
"txtPartNo" : "00P",
"txtSerialNo" : "00S",
"txtProductName" : "Watch",
"traderId" : ObjectId("5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2")
```

I want to search a product based on its name and traderId for which I used

```
db.getCollection('product').find( {$and:[{'txtProductName':"Watch"},{"traderId" : ObjectId("5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2")}]})
```

its working fine but now if a user have input model no then it shoud use model number also to search for a product if the user have not input the model no then it should without model number

So My question is do I have to use cases like this

```
if(req.body.modelNo)
    db.getCollection('product').find( {$and:[{'txtProductName':"Watch"},{"traderId" : ObjectId("5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2")},{'txtModelCode':"00M"}]})
else
  db.getCollection('product').find( {$and:[{'txtProductName':"Watch"},{"traderId" : ObjectId("5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2")}]})
```

or is there a way to do this without making cases I have to do this for multiple condtions so I am trying not to use cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the query object first then add the extra key with a conditional check. No need to explicitly use the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator when specifying a comma separated list of expressions as it's implicitly provided:

```
let query = {
    'txtProductName': 'Watch',
    'traderId': ObjectId('5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2')
};

if (req.body.modelNo) query['txtModelCode'] = req.body.modelNo;
db.getCollection('product').find(query);
```

---

If using the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator, you can push the additional query into an array then use the list for the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator:

```
let andOperator = [
    { 'txtProductName': 'Watch' },
    { 'traderId': ObjectId('5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2') }
];

if (req.body.modelNo) andOperator.push({ 'txtModelCode': req.body.modelNo });
// if (req.body.modelNo) andOperator = [...andOperator, { 'txtModelCode': req.body.modelNo }];
db.getCollection('product').find({ '$and': andOperator });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would have done this in this way

First, you should send a json of specific from to backend. for example

```
 [{'txtModelCode':"00M"},{'txtPartNo':"AC"},{'Yts':"xyz"}]
              OR
 [{'txtModelCode':"00M"},{'txtPartNo':"AC"}]

              OR
 [{'txtModelCode':"00M"}]
```

This is the payload that you should expect in `req.body`. And finally you can use it in your `find()` criteria. Something like

```
db.getCollection('product').find( {$and:[{'txtProductName':"Watch"},
{"traderId" : ObjectId("5ac5fb29b0f9b3444e6c1ef2")}, ...req.body]})
```

`...` is called spread operator. **Spread syntax** allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded.  Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

This will make it totally dynamic. Any scaling in collection can directly be used in `find` criteria. you never have to add extra line of code